# How to make sure the cursor comes up automatically in the text space under the question so that user can start writing the answers right away?

Tags: javascript, html, cursor

I just want to make sure the cursor starts blinking in the text box when the page loads. This code has already been written.

```
<input
  #inputElement
  type="{{ fieldData.type || 'text' }}"
  id="form-input"
  class="fi-input-general input-form"
  placeholder="{{ fieldData.placeholder || 'Type your answer' }}"
  [(ngModel)]="modelValue"
  matInput
  (input)="handleDataChange()"
  yr-integer
/>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to set the focus to the element.

Comment: You can use HTML input attribute autofocus to achieve it, ```<input id="xyz" autofocus/> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `focus()` method to set the focus to the element when the page opens.

```
document.getElementById("form-input").focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

First, add `autofocus` property to a input element.

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="text" name="id" autofocus><br>
<input type="text" name="department"><br>
```

Second, use javascript `focus` function.

```
# HTML

<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="text" name="id><br>
<input type="text" name="department"><br>

# JAVASCRIPT

document.getElementsByName("id")[0].focus()
```